# Multiple timings in a single cron

Tags: scheduled-apex, cron

I want to schedule a job which wil run nightly at 7 PM ET and 8 PM ET.

http://www.cronmaker.com/ provides a wizard to construct the scheduling string.  Is it possible to schedule both runs in one string ?

If it is only for 7 PM ET, then:

```
0 0 19 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SUN *
```

I want Batch will run at 7 PM then after 1 hour 8 PM ET.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) the `hours` value supports the "`,`" special character, which means you are able to supply a comma separated list of hours:

```
0 0 19,20 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SUN *
```

Alternatively you could use "`-`" to specify a range and because your seconds and minutes are set to zero it will only run on the hour:

```
0 0 19-20 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SUN *
```

As your `days` are all the days from Sunday till Friday you can use a range for those as well. The last value is an optional `year` so you don't need to include the `*` for it. Making these changes would mean your expression is:

```
0 0 19-20 ? * SUN-FRI
```